# there was an error in evaluating the test script syntax error unexpected token?

Tags: php, frameworks, postman, slim

**Index.php**

In this service, i want to insert details in the database by POST method, But it gives me some error so please help me to solve out it..
Here is my code -

```
app->post('/createprovider', function () use ($app) {
    verifyRequiredParams(array('fullname', 'email', 'mobile', 'password','business_name', 'email_work', 'phone_work', 'address', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'category'));
    $response = array();
    $fullname = $app->request->post('fullname');
    $email = $app->request->post('email');
    $mobile = $app->request->post('mobile');
    $password = $app->request->post('password');
    $business_name = $app->request->post('business_name');
    $email_work = $app->request->post('email_work');
    $phone_work = $app->request->post('phone_work');
    $address = $app->request->post('address');
    $latitude = $app->request->post('latitude');
    $longitude = $app->request->post('longitude');
    $category = $app->request->post('category');
    $db = new DbOperation();
    $res = $db->createprovider($fullname, $email, $mobile, $password, $business_name, $email_work, $phone_work, $address, $latitude, $longitude, $category);
    if ($res == 0) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "You are successfully registered";
        echoResponse(201, $response);
    } else if ($res == 1) {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred while registereing";
        echoResponse(200, $response);
    } else if ($res == 2) {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Sorry, this student  already existed";
        echoResponse(200, $response);
    }
});
```

**This Is function in dboperation.php**

```
 public function createprovider($fullname,$email,$mobile,$pass,$business_name,$email_work,$phone_work,$address,$latitude,$longitude, $category){
        if (!$this->isProviderExists($email)) {
            $password = md5($pass);
            //$apikey = $this->generateApiKey();
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO nesbaty_provider(fullname, email, mobile, password, business_name, email_work, phone_work, address, latitude, longitude, category) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

            $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $fullname, $email, $mobile, $password, $business_name, $email_work, $phone_work, $address, $latitude, $longitude, $category);

            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            if ($result) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `md5` is NOT a secure way of hashing passwords. Switch to using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: `return 0;enter code here` maybe this meant to be `return 0;//enter code here` ?

Comment: apart md5 i want just insert data at this time!!!

Comment: Please give the full error. The line number is the second most important part of the stack..

Comment: There was an error in evaluating the test script:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
in POSTMAN

Comment: Apart from the title - There's no mention of what you're seeing in Postman here. Can you update the question with the test script that you've added to Postman.

Comment: I want to clarify. In the actual code it should be `$app->post('/createprovider', ...);` not `app->post('/createprovider', ...);`? and can you successfully insert data into MySQL? What is 
 `echoResponse()` declaration?

Comment: No i am not able to insert data in my sql.....
nothing in respose

Comment: i am getting response
Return 1
so it will print 
{"error":true,"message":"Oops! An error occurred while registereing"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDO's execute() function returns `true` on success and `false` on failure.

See [PDO's Execute() function](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

You are introducing confusion by negating this in your if statement inside the `createprovider` function.
So you have basically have contradicting if blocks, as a result your overall logic is broken but your code needs a few changes.

This should work fine:

```
$app->post(...
...
if ($res == 1) {
    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "You are successfully registered";
    echoResponse(201, $response);
} else if ($res == 0) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred while registereing";
    echoResponse(200, $response);
} else if ($res == 2) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Sorry, this student  already existed";
    echoResponse(200, $response);
}
...
```

Then inside `createprovider()`:

```
...
$stmt->close();
if ($result) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
...
```

Also for a more "RESTful" implementation you shouldn't use code "2XX" for errors.